# Converting A List With Python

Tags: python, list

I have a large list of names which is in this format

```
list1 = ["apple", "orange", "banana", "pine-apple"]
```

And I want it in this format

```
list1 = ["'apple'", "'orange'", "'banana'", "'pine-apple'"]
```

Basically, I want to add punctuation marks to every single word in the list
but since the list is too large, I can't do it manually.
So is there any python function or way to do this task. Thank You.

Comment: So you want an automated way to edit the python code in your text editor? Which text editor are you using?

Answer (score 2):

The names in python are already strings enclosed in the quotes like you have shown here. I am supposing you want to wrap the string with specific quote to look this `'"apple"'` or `"'apple'"`. To do so, you should use the following snippet

```py
q = "'" # this will be wrapped around the string

list1 = ['apple','orange','banana','pine-apple']
list1 = [q+x+q for x in list1]
```

For reference, the syntax I have used in last line is known as [list comprehension](https://realpython.com/list-comprehension-python/#using-list-comprehensions)

#### According to latest comment posted by @xdhmoore

If you are using vim/nano (linux/macos) or notepad(windows), then i would rather suggest you to use IDLE python (shipped with python setup)

Answer (score 0):

Str function is the built in function to convert a value into string.
You can run this code;

```
 For i in range(len(list1)):
       new = str(list1[i])
       list1.remove(list[i])
       list1.append(new)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `for` loop to process each line, two ways to go

```py
text = "list1 = [apple,orange,banana,pine-apple]"
start = text.find('[')+1
stop  = text.find(']')
lst = text[start:stop].split(',')                       # ['apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pine-apple']
new_lst = [f'"{item}"' for item in lst]                 # ['"apple"', '"orange"', '"banana"', '"pine-apple"']
new_text1 = text[:start]+','.join(new_lst)+text[stop:]  # 'list1 = ["apple","orange","banana","pine-apple"]'
```

```py
text = "list1 = [apple,orange,banana,pine-apple]"
new_text2 = text.replace('[', '["').replace(']', '"]').replace(',', '","')
```